# Proof of Fermat's two square theorem, need an explanation of one step

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[On wikipedia there's a proof to the theorem by infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)

I have a problem with understanding step four, namely why we 'can' write $a$ and $b$ in such forms ( $a= mx\pm c$ and $b =nx \pm d$)?
What leads to such assumption? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ and $x$ are positive integers, the remainder theorem is usually stated as $a=mx+r$ with $0\le r\lt x$.  But it can also be written as $a=mx+r$ with $0\le|r|\le x/2$.  For example, $23=2\cdot8+7$ gives $7$ for a remainder, while $23=3\cdot8-1$ gives $-1$ as the remainder whose absolute value is no greater than $8/2=4$.

Comment: This indeed explains it nicely. Thank you.

Could you also explain the last step to me? I don't understand the two sentences starting from 'If it divides' to 'would all be constant and equal to (2n)!'

I feel there was some huge skip there. I mean, I get the reasoning behind the differences being divisible by p and all that, but where did the sequence with k come from, and how was the difference calculated?

Comment: @Satsuki, you can post a new question.

Comment: I have posted it now.